# How to use flags in a bash script with for loop?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I'm learning bash recently I want to use flags in this `for` loop to read head and tail of file.

```
for filename in "$1"

    do
    echo $filename
    head -n "$2" $filename | tail -n "$3"
  done
```

I want to use flags like `-f` (instead of `$1`), `-h` (instead of `$2`), `-t` (instead of `$3`).

Comment: `for filename in "$1"` is only going to iterate once.  If `$1` is a space separated list of files, you can iterate over them by removing the quotes and using `for filename in $1`...but don't do that.

Comment: use something like getopts, getopt, or roll your own with something like:
`while $#; do if [ "$1" = "-f" ];then shift; f_arg="$1"; shift; elif ...`
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html

Comment: you should clarify your question to show how you would want to use the flags.  my understanding is you want to do: `./myscript -f file1 file2 ... fileN -h N1 -t N2`

Comment: not an answer to your question but you can do this loop with: `awk -v head=10 -v tail=2 'FNR==1{print FILENAME}FNR<=head && FNR>head-tail' file1 ... fileN` or (`file*`).

Comment: _use flags like -f (instead of $1),_ .... What exactly do you mean by this, and why is it specific to a loop? Pleasae provide a specification of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to cram all the filenames into a single argument, allow multiple arguments to specify paths.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set defaults
h=10
t=5

while test -n "$1"; do
        filename=$1
        case $filename in
        -h) h=$2; shift; shift; continue;;
        -t) t=$2; shift; shift; continue;;
        esac

        if ! test "$h" -gt 0 || ! test "$t" -gt 0; then
                echo "Invalid entry" >&2;
                exit 1
        fi

        echo "$filename"
        # head -n "$h" $filename | tail -n "$t"
        d=$(( h - t ))
        sed -ne "$d,${h}p" "$filename"
        shift
done
```